# Can't run Yocto image with runqemu like described in documentation

Tags: yocto, qemu

I would like to run a Yocto image in QEMU but the way how it's described in [the documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6.1/brief-yoctoprojectqs/brief-yoctoprojectqs.html) doesn't work.

To verify I'm not doing anything wrong i followed the steps in the quick build guide:

- install required packages
- clone poky
- checkout correct version
- source build environment
- set machine to qemux86 in local.conf
- add sstate-mirrors and allow parallel build
- start bitbake core-image-sato
- do something else for the next few hours

when I try now to run that image in qemu like describe in the documentation:

```
runqemu qemux86
```

I just get the following output, nothing happens:

```
runqemu - INFO - Running MACHINE=qemux86 bitbake -e...
runqemu - INFO - Continuing with the following parameters:

KERNEL: [/mnt/wwn-0x50014ee0576fe9ef- part1/test_python3_in_yocto/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/bzImage--4.14.76+git0+3435617380_2c5caa7e84-r0-qemux86-20190305114605.bin]
MACHINE: [qemux86]
FSTYPE: [ext4]
ROOTFS: [/mnt/wwn-0x50014ee0576fe9ef-part1/test_python3_in_yocto/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/core-image-base-qemux86-20190305151244.rootfs.ext4]
CONFFILE: [/mnt/wwn-0x50014ee0576fe9ef-part1/test_python3_in_yocto/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/core-image-base-qemux86-20190305151244.qemuboot.conf]

runqemu - INFO - Setting up tap interface under sudo
runqemu - INFO - Network configuration: 192.168.7.2::192.168.7.1:255.255.255.0
runqemu - INFO - Running /mnt/wwn-0x50014ee0576fe9ef-part1/test_python3_in_yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-helper-native/1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qemu-system-i386 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=52:54:00:12:34:02 -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -drive file=/mnt/wwn-0x50014ee0576fe9ef-part1/test_python3_in_yocto/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/core-image-base-qemux86-20190305151244.rootfs.ext4,if=virtio,format=raw -vga vmware -show-cursor -usb -device usb-tablet -device virtio-rng-pci   -cpu pentium2 -m 256 -serial mon:vc -serial null -kernel /mnt/wwn-0x50014ee0576fe9ef-part1/test_python3_in_yocto/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/bzImage--4.14.76+git0+3435617380_2c5caa7e84-r0-qemux86-20190305114605.bin -append 'root=/dev/vda rw highres=off  mem=256M ip=192.168.7.2::192.168.7.1:255.255.255.0 vga=0 uvesafb.mode_option=640x480-32 oprofile.timer=1 uvesafb.task_timeout=-1 '
```

When I try to run qemu without graphics I get a kernel panic:

```
runqemu nographic qemux86
...

[    6.171521] EXT4-fs (vda): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    6.172937] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 253:0.
[    6.175806] devtmpfs: error mounting -2
[    6.237143] Freeing unused kernel memory: 852K
[    6.238001] Write protecting the kernel text: 8752k
[    6.238722] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 2376k
[    6.244382] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin.
[    6.245455] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.14.76-yocto-standard #1
[    6.245913] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.11.0-0-g63451fca13-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/4
[    6.246730] Call Trace:
[    6.247788]  dump_stack+0x58/0x72
[    6.248071]  ? rest_init+0x90/0xc0
[    6.248320]  panic+0x94/0x1c6
[    6.248529]  ? rest_init+0xc0/0xc0
[    6.248807]  kernel_init+0xda/0xf0
[    6.249046]  ret_from_fork+0x2e/0x38
[    6.249834] Kernel Offset: 0xd800000 from 0xc1000000 (relocation range: 0xc0000000-0xd07dbfff)
[    6.250595] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentat.
```

Is there something missing in the documentation?

I also tried different images...

- core-image-sato
- core-image-base
- core-image-minimal

and finally I tried it with version 2.5.2 (sumo) instead of 2.6.1 (thud)... but no change...

When I googled for that issue I didn't really find anything helpful except increasing the memory, which didn't change anything, so I hope anyone here someone knows whats wrong...

Comment: Did you try to run qemu without runqemu wrapper?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, if I figure it out I'll post here.

Answer (score 2):

Probably missing an appendage to the second parameter.
Browse to the folder in the error message, and check the directory qemux86 exists, chances are it doesn't.

I had to

```
runqemu qemux86-64
```

and not

```
runqemu qemux86
```

Comment: try something like this ->  runqemu qemux86-64 slirp nographic   
   https://github.com/crops/poky-container/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed `MACHINE` variable in your `local.conf` file in build directory, check out the file and make sure your image name was identical.